# Chrome randomly sends me to modem page 192.168.8.1

Tags: google-chrome, modem, usb-modem

I have a GSM modem plugged into my computer and ever since I set it up Chrome randomly sends me to 192.168.8.1 when I am browsing the web.

I have tried disabling "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" which did not fix it.

How do I stop this? It's extremely annoying.

Comment: Did you set it as chrome homepage to open it everytime you start chrome?

Comment: No. Also it appears to be working as some type of firewall. Its weird.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I disabled the firewall in the modem settings.

Comment: That's not a real fix. And you should **not disable firewall**.